# Surprising failure of unification in Idris

Tags: parsing, unification, idris

I'm trying to make what one might call a decidable parser in Idris. At first I am just looking at parsing natural numbers, but have ran into an unexpected problem. A minimum example of the code that produces it is this:

```
data Digit : Char -> Type where
  Zero  : Digit '0'
  One   : Digit '1'

digitToNat : Digit a -> Nat
digitToNat Zero  = 0
digitToNat One   = 1

natToChar : Nat -> Char
natToChar Z = '0'
natToChar (S Z) = '1'

natToDigit : (n : Nat) -> Digit (natToChar n)
natToDigit Z = Zero
natToDigit (S Z) = One
```

I would expect this to compile, but instead I get

```
When elaborating right hand side of natToDigit:
Can't unify
        Digit '0'
with
        Digit (natToChar 0)

Specifically:
        Can't unify
                '0'
        with
                natToChar 0
```

But `natToChar 0` clearly equals `'0'`, so I don't understand what the problem here is.

**Update**

I have also asked a question more directly related to what I am trying to do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095563/generating-run-time-proofs-with-type-predicates-in-idris).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type checker won't reduce `natToChar` because it isn't total - this is basically to prevent you using some partially defined function to prove something which isn't true.

If you're writing this to work on data which turns up at run-time, possibly what you need is `Dec` or `Maybe`:

```
natToChar : (n : Nat) -> Maybe Char
```