# Generating run time proofs with type predicates in Idris

Tags: parsing, unification, idris, decidable

I am using this type to reason about strings on which decidable parsing can be performed:

```
data Every : (a -> Type) -> List a -> Type where
  Nil : {P : a -> Type} -> Every P []
  (::) : {P : a -> Type} -> P x -> Every P xs -> Every P (x::xs)
```

For example, defining the digits [0-9] like this:

```
data Digit : Char -> Type where
  Zero  : Digit '0'
  One   : Digit '1'
  Two   : Digit '2'
  Three : Digit '3'
  Four  : Digit '4'
  Five  : Digit '5'
  Six   : Digit '6'
  Seven : Digit '7'
  Eight : Digit '8'
  Nine  : Digit '9'

digitToNat : Digit a -> Nat
digitToNat Zero  = 0
digitToNat One   = 1
digitToNat Two   = 2
digitToNat Three = 3
digitToNat Four  = 4
digitToNat Five  = 5
digitToNat Six   = 6
digitToNat Seven = 7
digitToNat Eight = 8
digitToNat Nine  = 9
```

then we can have the following functions:

```
fromDigits : Every Digit xs -> Nat -> Nat
fromDigits [] k = 0
fromDigits (x :: xs) k = (digitToNat x) * (pow 10 k) + fromDigits xs (k-1)

s2n : (s : String) -> {auto p : Every Digit (unpack s)} -> Nat
s2n {p} s = fromDigits p (length s - 1)
```

This `s2n` function will now work fine at compile time, but then that isn't very useful in of itself. To use it at runtime we must construct the proof `Every Digit (unpack s)` before we can use the function.

So I think I now want to write something like this function:

```
every : (p : a -> Type) -> (xs : List a) -> Maybe $ Every p xs
```

That or we want to return either a proof of membership or a proof of non-membership, but I'm not entirely sure how to do either of these things in a general way. So instead I tried doing the `Maybe` version for just characters:

```
every : (p : Char -> Type) -> (xs : List Char) -> Maybe $ Every p xs
every p [] = Just []
every p (x :: xs) with (decEq x '0')
  every p ('0' :: xs) | (Yes Refl)  = Just $ p '0' :: !(every p xs)
  every p (x   :: xs) | (No contra) = Nothing
```

But then I get this unification error:

```
    Can't unify
            Type
    with
            p '0'

    Specifically:
            Can't unify
                    Type
            with
                    p '0'
```

But `p` *is* of type `Char -> Type`. I'm not sure what is causing this unification failure, but think the problem may be related to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095335/surprising-failure-of-unification-in-idris).

Is this a sensible approach to what I am trying to do? I feel like it is a little to much work at the moment, and more general versions of these functions should be possible. It would be nice if the `auto` keyword could be used to write a function gives you a `Maybe proof` or an `Either proof proofThatItIsNot`, in a similar way to how the `DecEq` class works.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `fmap (p '0' ::) (every p xs)` instead of `Just $ p '0' :: !(every p xs)`?

Comment: That is better style, certainly, thanks for the suggestion (I was writing the code quite quickly). An extra pair of parens is needed for Idris to accept it: `map ((p '0') ::) (every p xs)`. (Not also `fmap` is just `map` in Idris). 

Doesn't change the error though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message is correct: you provided a value of type `Type`, but you need a value of type `p '0'`. You are also correct that `p` is of type `Char -> Type`, and therefore that `p '0'` is of type `Type`. However, `p '0'` is not of type `p '0'`.

Perhaps the issue would be easier to see with simpler types: `3` has type `Int`, and `Int` has type `Type`, but `Int` does not have type `Int`.

Now, how do we fix the problem? Well, `p` is a predicate, meaning that it constructs types whose inhabitants are proofs of this predicate. So the value of type `p '0'` we need to provide would be a proof, in this case a proof that `'0'` is a digit. `Zero` happens to be such a proof. But in the signature of `every`, the `p` variable isn't talking about digits: it's an abstract predicate, about which we know nothing. For this reason, there are no values we could use instead of `p '0'`. We must instead change the type of `every`.

One possibility would be to write a more specialized version version of `every`, one which would only work for the particular predicate `Digit` instead of working for an arbitrary `p`:

```
everyDigit : (xs : List Char) -> Maybe $ Every Digit xs
everyDigit [] = Just []
everyDigit (x :: xs) with (decEq x '0')
  everyDigit ('0' :: xs) | (Yes Refl)  = Just $ Zero :: !(everyDigit xs)
  everyDigit (x   :: xs) | (No contra) = Nothing
```

Instead of incorrectly using the value `p '0'` in a spot which needs a value of type `p '0'`, I have used the value `Zero` in a spot which now needs a value of type `Digit '0'`.

Another possibility would be to modify `every` so that in addition to the predicate `p` which gives a proof type for every `Char`, we would also receive a proof-making function `mkPrf` which would give the corresponding proof value for every `Char`, when possible.

```
every : (p : Char -> Type)
     -> (mkPrf : (c : Char) -> Maybe $ p c)
     -> (xs : List Char)
     -> Maybe $ Every p xs
every p mkPrf [] = Just []
every p mkPrf (x :: xs) with (mkPrf x)
  every p mkPrf (x :: xs) | Just prf = Just $ prf :: !(every p mkPrf xs)
  every p mkPrf (x :: xs) | Nothing  = Nothing
```

I am no longer pattern-matching on the `Char`, instead I am asking `mkPrf` to examine the `Char`. I then pattern-match on the result, to see if it found a proof. It is the implementation of `mkPrf` which pattern-matches on the `Char`.

```
everyDigit' : (xs : List Char) -> Maybe $ Every Digit xs
everyDigit' = every Digit mkPrf
  where
    mkPrf : (c : Char) -> Maybe $ Digit c
    mkPrf '0' = Just Zero
    mkPrf _   = Nothing
```

In the implementation of `mkPrf`, we are again constructing a proof for the concrete type `Digit '0'` instead of the abstract type `p '0'`, so `Zero` is an acceptable proof.